# JavaScript Promises not passing right value in Chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sequelize.js

I have a random generated string that I set as a value for a property in my database table. On a successful update to my record I then send an email containing that same token that was used in the database record. Unfortunately the token parameter in my then statement does not contain the token and instead is replaced with a value of 1. Why is this happening and does it have something to do with how promises functionality works?

**This is an example console log and SQL update that appears in my code:**

```
This is the token: 78a4543cdd4cfd9d8c7fbad89aed9f902e07c372
Executing (default): UPDATE `user` SET `reset_password_token`='78a4543cdd4cfd9d8c7fbad89aed9f902e07c372',`reset_password_expires`='2016-04-02 14:46:13',`updatedAt`='2016-04-02 13:46:13' WHERE `email` = 'tester@gmail.com'
Then this token: 1
```

**POST Method:**

```
.post(function(req, res){
        async.waterfall([
        function(done){
            crypto.randomBytes(20, function(err, buf){
                var resetToken = buf.toString('hex');
                done(err, resetToken);
            });
        }, (function(token, done){


            console.log('This is the token: ' + token);


            models.User.update({
                resetPasswordToken: token,
                resetPasswordExpires: Date.now() + 3600000
            }, {
            where: { email: req.body.email }

            }).then(function(token, user, done){


            console.log('Then this token: ' + token);


            var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(sgTransport(options));

            var mailOptions = {
                from: '"Test Email" <test@mywebsite.com',
                to: 'tester@gmail.com',
                subject: 'Password Rest Confirmation',
                text: 'You are receiving this because you (or someone else) have requested the reset of the password for your account.\n\n' +
                        'Please click on the following link, or paste this into your browser to complete the process:\n\n' +
                        'http://' + req.headers.host + '/reset/' + token + '\n\n' +
                        'If you did not request this, please ignore this email and your password will remain unchanged.\n'
            };

            transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
                if(error){
                    return console.log(error);
                }
                console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);

            });
                res.redirect('/');
                //res.redirect('/password-reset-confirmation') Make a confirmation page with information or just send a flash message
            })
        })], function(error){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    })  
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `token` receives the value `1` because *the `update()` operation returns the number of affected records*. In this case, there was a single record updated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This was exactly what I was looking for